# Are these the definitions of $\text{int}_CA$ and $\partial_CA$?

Tags: general-topology

Are the following correct?

$$\text{int}_CA=\{ x\in C: \exists_{\epsilon>0}(B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap C )\subset A\}$$ and

$$\partial_CA=\{x\in C:\forall_{\epsilon>0}B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap \text{int}_CA\neq \emptyset \text{ and } \\ B_{\epsilon}(x)\cap \text{ext}_CA\neq \emptyset\}$$

with $\text{ext}_CA=C-cl_CA$

Comment: What is $C$? A metric space? What is $B_\epsilon(x)$? A ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $x$? Why do you take $B_\epsilon(x)\cap C$? How can that be anything else then $B_\epsilon(x)$? Does "$\text{int}$" stand for the interior and "$\partial$" for boundary? What are your definitions of the interior and boundary in order for the question to make any sense? Why did you tag the question with "general-topology"? What have you tried? So many questions...

Comment: Your statement about the exterior of A relative to C is wrong.

Comment: @WilliamElliot my bad... What about now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interior is correct; note that $B^C_\varepsilon(x)$ (the relative open ball of radius $\varepsilon>0$ for $x \in C$) equals, by definition of the relative metric $d_C$ on $C$ as $d_C=d\restriction_{C \times C}$, the set $B_\epsilon(x) \cap C$: $y$ is in the relative ball in $C$ iff $y \in C$ and $d_C(x,y)=d(x,y) < \varepsilon$. So the first set is just those $x \in C$ who have a $d_C$-ball inside $A$, which is just (a/the) definition of $\operatorname{int}_C(A)$.

The boundary statement is wrongly "translated". A point in the boundary of $A$ is one whose every $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood intersects $A$ and its complement.

So working inside $C$:

$$\partial_C A =\{ x \in C\mid \forall \varepsilon>0: B^C_\varepsilon(x) \cap A \neq \emptyset \land B^C_\varepsilon(x) \cap (C\setminus A) \neq \emptyset \}$$

which can be slightly rewritten as

$$\partial_C A =\{ x \in C\mid \forall \varepsilon>0: B_\varepsilon(x) \cap C \cap A \neq \emptyset \land B_\varepsilon(x) \cap C \cap A^\complement \neq \emptyset\}$$

We cannot ensure that $B_\varepsilon(x)$ intersects the relative interior of $A$, as this could well be empty. Consider a singleton set in the reals or its subspaces, e.g.

Alternatively, in any space, the boundary is just the closure minus the interior, so we also have

$$\partial_C A = \operatorname{cl}_C \setminus \operatorname{int}_C(A)$$

if you want a formula with the interior in it.

Comment: Henno, many thanks! what about the exterior? Did I defined correctly?